# c# socket connect & receive data

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have a function that connects to a socket:

```
public void Connect(string ip, ushort port)
{
    try
    {
        m_clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        m_recv_buffer = new TransferBuffer(8192, 0, 0);
        m_localSecurity = new Session(UsageMode.Client);

        IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        m_clientSocket.Connect(localEP);

        m_clientSocket.BeginReceive(m_recv_buffer.Buffer, 0, m_recv_buffer.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceiveData, m_clientSocket);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            Debugger(string.Format("[ClientConnect] Socket Exception: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message), System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
        }
        else
        {
            Debugger(string.Format("[ClientConnect] Socket Exception: {0}", ex), System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
        }
    }
}
```

And function that is receiving data:

```
private void OnReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket asyncState = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            if (asyncState.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    int readCount = asyncState.EndReceive(ar);
                    if (readCount > 0)
                    {
                        m_recv_buffer.Offset = 0;
                        m_recv_buffer.Size = readCount;
                        TransferBuffer buf = new TransferBuffer(m_recv_buffer.Buffer, 0, readCount, false);
                        m_localSecurity.Recv(buf);
                        Array.Clear(m_recv_buffer.Buffer, 0, m_recv_buffer.Buffer.Length);
                    }

                    asyncState.BeginReceive(m_recv_buffer.Buffer, 0, m_recv_buffer.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceiveData, asyncState);
                }
                catch (SocketException sex)
                {
                    Debugger(string.Format("[OnReceiveData] Socket Exception: {0}", sex),System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debugger(string.Format("[OnReceiveData] Exception: {0}", ex), System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
                }
            }
        }
```

On some rare occasions when my internet is lagging or is in anyway unstable i am stuck in a `OnReceiveData` function. 
`Socket` connects and stays connected but I do not get any response from the server so `OnReceiveData` function is calling it self and gets stuck in a loop.

Is there a way to add a `timeout` or any other check on receiving data part?

Comment: There's no loop to get stuck in... if you run in the debugger and pause execution when it gets "stuck" what line is it on?

Comment: I personally never use callback functions. Instead I use a separate thread. It makes things a lot easier to control.

Comment: Is `TransferBuffer` your own class? If so can you include the code for the constructor you are calling?

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: asyncState.BeginReceive(m_recv_buffer.Buffer, 0, m_recv_buffer.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceiveData, asyncState);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like `AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();` take a look at the following solution

[Implementation-of-Connecting-a-Socket-with-Timeout](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31514/Implementation-of-Connecting-a-Socket-with-Timeout)

Comment: I have tried that with 5 seconds time out. Same problem. Connection to socket appears to be solid.

Comment: When you say solid is the sending  socket actually disconnected

Comment: No its not. Socket connection is not a problem. Problem is I do not get any response from a server.

Comment: private void OnReceiveData(IAsyncResult ar) is beging called and  if (asyncState.Connected) is allways true so i proceed to   if (readCount > 0) which is not so again  asyncState.BeginReceive(m_recv_buffer.Buffer, 0, m_recv_buffer.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceiveData, asyncState); is called

Comment: ... and this cycle is repeating it self

Comment: Have you tried to actually cancel your async call if it doe not send data? I think it not really a timeout if connection is solid

Comment: That wouldn't be a good option to modify code like that becase i dont have call to that function anywhere else so if i do not call it when if (readCount > 0)  is false i drop out of receiving packets.

Comment: based on your suggestion all of the pockets are not getting received already